# Mi serpiente en Python no se mueve correctamente en mi juego da error : list index out range

Tags: python-3.x

Estoy intentando crear un juego de serpientes en Python y estoy teniendo problemas para que la serpiente se mueva correctamente. El código que tengo actualmente muestra la serpiente en la pantalla, pero al mover hacia abajo cuando presiono las teclas "s" sale IndexError: list index out of range.

He intentado agregar algunos bucles de control para manejar la entrada del usuario, pero todavía no puedo hacer que la serpiente deje de darme ese mismo error.

Aquí está mi código actual:

```
import os
import random
import readchar

pos_x = 0
pos_y = 1

num_of_map_objects = 11

obstacle_definition = """\
##########################
                     #####
################     #####
################     #####
##########
#################   ######  
##########              ##
##############        ####
##############
####################   ###
########    ######       #
######                 ###
#######   ########## 
#####    #########       # 
##########################\
"""

my_position = [0, 1]
tail_lengt = 0
tail = []
map_objects = []

end_game = False
died = False

#create obstacle map
obstacle_definition = [list(row) for row in obstacle_definition.split("\n")]

map_width = len(obstacle_definition[0])
map_height = len(obstacle_definition)
#main lopp
while not end_game:
    os.system("cls")
    #generate random objects on the map
    while len(map_objects) < num_of_map_objects:
        new_position = [random.randint(0, map_width - 1), random.randint(0, map_height - 1)]

        if new_position not in map_objects and new_position != my_position:
            map_objects.append(new_position)
    # Draw Map
    print("+" + "-" * map_width * 2 + "+")
    for coordinate_y in range(map_height):
        print("|", end="")
        for coordinate_x in range(map_width):
            char_to_draw = "  "
            object_in_cell = None
            tail_in_cell = None
            for map_object in map_objects:
                if map_object[pos_x] == coordinate_x and map_object[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
                    char_to_draw = " *"
                    object_in_cell = map_object
            for tail_piece in tail:
                if tail_piece[pos_x] == coordinate_x and tail_piece[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
                    char_to_draw = " @"
                    tail_in_cell = tail_piece
            if my_position[pos_x] == coordinate_x and my_position[pos_y] == coordinate_y:
                char_to_draw = " @"

                if object_in_cell:
                    map_objects.remove(object_in_cell)
                    tail_lengt += 1
                if tail_in_cell:
                    end_game = True
                    died = True
            if coordinate_y < len(obstacle_definition) and coordinate_x < len(obstacle_definition[coordinate_y]) and obstacle_definition[coordinate_y][coordinate_x] == "#":
                char_to_draw = "##"
            print("{}".format(char_to_draw), end="")
        print("|")
    print("+" + "-" * map_width * 2 + "+")

    #ask user where he wants to move
    #direction = input("¿Dónde te quieres mover? [WASD]:")
    direction = readchar.readkey()


    new_position = None

    if direction == "w":
        new_position = [my_position[pos_x], (my_position[pos_y] - 1) % map_width]
    elif direction == "s":
        new_position = [my_position[pos_x], (my_position[pos_y] + 1) % map_width]
    elif direction == "a":
        new_position = [(my_position[pos_x] - 1) % map_width, my_position[pos_y]]
    elif direction == "d":
        new_position = [(my_position[pos_x] + 1) % map_width, my_position[pos_y]]
    elif direction == "q":
        end_game = True
    if new_position:
        if obstacle_definition[new_position[pos_y]][new_position[pos_x]] != "#":
            tail.insert(0, my_position.copy())
            tail = tail[:tail_lengt]
            my_position = new_position

if died:
    print("Has muerto!")
```

#eso es todo el codigo...

## **Me da este error.. ayuda porfa:**

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
 File "mazectmre.py", line 99, in <module>                                 
    if obstacle_definition[new_position[pos_y]][new_position[pos_x]] != "#":
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**El error invisible**.
Esta es tu definición del escenario:

```
obstacle_definition = """\
##########################
                     #####
################     #####
################     #####
##########
#################   ######  
##########              ##
##############        ####
##############
####################   ###
########    ######       #
######                 ###
#######   ########## 
#####    #########       # 
##########################\
"""
```

Esta es la definición correcta:

```
obstacle_definition = """\
##########################
                     #####
################     #####
################     #####
##########                
#################   ######
##########              ##
##############        ####
##############            
####################   ###
########    ######        
######                 ###
#######   ##########      
#####    #########       #
##########################\
"""
```

Tan igualitas, y tan diferentes, que la tuya hace colapsar al programa.
Que si estoy loco?, te invito a hacer una prueba, selecciona con el mouse, tu definición y luego has lo propio con la mía...
Cuando eso lo traduces a una matriz, te quedan las 4 primeras filas de 26 espacios, la 5° de 10, la sexta de 28.... etc, cuando "bajas" de la fila 4 a la 5, estás entre las columnas 17 y 21, quieres acceder (por ej.) a la fila 5 columna 17, y solo tiene 10 columnas... arrayBound...

Comment: ¡Gracias por tu respuesta! Probé el código que me sugeriste, pero lamentablemente todavía no pude resolver mi problema. El juego se ejecuta, pero la serpiente al mover hacia abajo sigue saliendo el error:  list index of range. No estoy seguro si esto se debe a algún problema en el código o en mi computadora. ¿Hay alguna otra cosa que podría probar? Agradecería cualquier otra sugerencia que tengas. ¡Gracias de nuevo por tu ayuda!

Comment: Edite la respuesta, fijate si  lo soluciona, sino me comentas.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! He hecho los cambios que sugeriste, pero aún así sigo recibiendo un error. ¿Tienes alguna otra sugerencia que pueda probar?

Comment: El mismo error u otro?

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Tu sugerencia de cambiar la definición de los obstáculos funcionó perfectamente en mi código y ahora todo está funcionando correctamente. Pero aun no entiendo mucho tal vez como soy nuevo.. en esto de la programacion, me sorprendio demasiado eso de que es el mismo diseño ya el mio no funciona y eso que es el mismo diseño.. eres un crack realmente aprecio tu tiempo y esfuerzo en ayudarme a resolver este problema. ¡Gracias de nuevo! :)

Comment: ¿Eso de los obstaculos como lo diseño correctamente?.. para q no me de ese mismo error de:  list index out of range  y la verdad como dices son "tan igualitas, y tan diferentes" eso de los obstaculos yo lo diseñe en el mismo editor de visual studio code y me salia el error ya mencionado.  Como lo hizo funcionar ud....?  ¡Gracias de nuevo!

Comment: Observa la linea "5", tu pusiste diez numerales, y le diste al salto de linea, yo puse diez numerales seguidos de dieciséis espacios, y después el salto de linea, el secreto esta en los espacios vacíos que no pusiste, hay varias formas de lidiar con eso, puedes crear array de tamaño prefijado, entonces siempre tendrá la longitud adecuada, otra forma sería siempre terminar cada fila con un "**#**", de esa manera se hace visible el tamaño de cada fila, y la tercera es la que usé yo, que es más propensa a errores, contar la cantidad justa de "pared" y "espacios".